# Что лучше для безопасности

Tags: dns

Подскажите, что лучше для использовать для безопасности в настройках : DNS over TLS или DNS over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это может стать предметом для обсуждения. С точки зрения сетевой безопасности DoT, возможно, лучше. DoT дает сетевым администраторам возможность отслеживать и блокировать DNS-запросы, что важно для выявления и остановки вредоносного трафика. При этом DoH-запросы скрыты в обычном трафике HTTPS, а это означает, что их невозможно легко заблокировать, не блокируя при этом весь прочий трафик HTTPS.

Тем не менее, с точки зрения конфиденциальности, можно утверждать, что DoH является более предпочтительным. С DoH DNS-запросы скрыты в обширном потоке HTTPS-трафика. Это дает сетевым администраторам меньшую видимость, но обеспечивает пользователям большую конфиденциальность.